# How to disconnect airplay device (apple tv) programmatically?

Tags: ios, external, avplayer, playback, airplay

I have multiple video players in my application and I am showing Airplay on one of my screen. But when user navigate away from that screen airplay stops and when I open any other screen with video player airplay starts again. So I want to remove/disconnect airplay manually when user moves away from my desired screen so Airplay should not start on other screens.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the video from external playback you need to set `AVPlayer`'s property `allowsExternalPlayback` to `NO`. The default value of this property is `YES`.  More info at [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387441-allowsexternalplayback?language=objc)